# Deformation of rational points in a family

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, hilbert-schemes, rational-points

Let $\mathcal{X} \to B$ be a family of smooth projective varieties over a field $K$ (possibly finite). Assume that each fiber $\mathcal{X}_b$ of the family has a $K$-rational point. Fix a pair $(p,\mathcal{X}_b)$ where $p$ is a $K$-rational point in $\mathcal{X}_b$ for some closed point $b \in B$. Under what condition is it true that if $\mathcal{X}_b$ deforms to $\mathcal{X}_c$ then the point $p$ deforms to a $K$-rational point in $\mathcal{X}_c$? For example as far as I understand a rationally connected variety deforms to a rationally connected variety. I am asking a similar question for rational points.

Comment: I am having trouble parsing this question.  Could you phrase this a little differently, or perhaps give an example?

Comment: @Starr: I have modified the question. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: I already deleted a comment where I misunderstood the question. It's hard to understand what you are really asking. Are you asking whether given $b,p$ as above, there exists a section of the family passing through $p$ and through a rational point in the fiber above $c$? I think the answer is no.

Comment: @Voloch: I am asking something similar. I am roughly asking that if a variety with a rational point deforms, when does the rational point deform with it? I think it is equivalent to what you say. I know that this is not true in general. So I am asking for conditions to impose on the members of the family so as to get a positive answer.

Comment: @Jana: Even though rationally connected varieties deform to rationally connected varieties, it is not true that rational curves in rationally connected varieties always deform in families.

Comment: Maybe what you are asking is what class of varieties over function fields satisfy the Hasse principle and weak approximation. That's an open problem but, if you use these keywords you will find some partial results.